# How can I fix this REST service to avoid ambiguous paths?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-hateoas

I'm using spring hateoas to create a rest service.  I have database entities which I'm exposing through the REST API.  To simplify, let's say I have an entity that has three fields as follows.

- `id` - a unique identifier
- `service` - a service this item belongs to
- `value` - a numeric attribute for this item

I am trying to implement the following URL schema:

`@RequestMapping(value = "")` - return a collection of all items
`@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}")` - return the specific item with this `id`
`@RequestMapping(value = "/{service}")` - return a collection of all items with this `service`

The problem here is the 2nd and 3rd paths are ambiguous and Spring doesn't know which `@RequestMapping` to match on if I try the URL below for example.

`http://localhost/123`

How can I deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}") 
@RequestMapping(value = "/service/{service}")
```

You don't have many choices ? But you could also query params with a bit refactoring.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}") 
public String myMethod(@RequestParam(value = "service") String service){}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you want `/{service} to return a collection with the specified service, a more "correct" approach is probably to add that to your "/" requestmapping as a query parameter.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "")
public CollectionResource getItems(@RequestParam(value = "service", required = false) String serviceType)
```

And use something like

```
http://localhost // return all
http://localhost/123 // return item with ID 123
http://localhost?service=abc // return all items with service abc
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what distinguishes an id from a service. If, for instance, an id is a number and a service a string of characters you can use regular expressions like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id:\\d+}") 
@RequestMapping(value = "/{service:[a-zA-Z]+}")
```

Comment: Nice tip but I don't have a guarantee that someone won't use a number as a service name in future so this won't work.